# A way to draw equidistant curve

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, computational-geometry, spline

I posted [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60902/formulas-for-equidistant-curves) on mathoverflow but I want to know your opinion regarding this also. What I want to do is to draw a curve that is always at a certain distance from the normal to the surface of a given curve. I know the formula of the given curve (a piecewise cubic spline). The problem appears to be when the deviation distance is more than the radius of the curve - the points get scrambled. Has anyone encountered such problem. Is there a nice solution?

Thanks for any ideas,

Iulian

**LATER:** The problem is perfectly described below by Mr. Wizard.

Comment: language-agnostic, my butt!  those words look like they're English but they don't parse!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: **NOTE: This answer isn't about avoiding corner-wrapping (which is a feature of strict equidistant curves).**

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve),

> The curve at a fixed offset from a given Bézier curve, often called an offset curve (lying "parallel" to the original curve, like the offset between rails in a railroad track), cannot be exactly formed by a Bézier curve (except in some trivial cases). However, there are heuristic methods that usually give an adequate approximation for practical purposes.

So, there are heuristic methods that you'll have to use to get an *approximation*. There's an academic paper called [Comparing offset curve approximation methods](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.109.8030&rep=rep1&type=pdf) including a comparison of 9 algorithms.

If you want to skip the research and just get a solution, take a look at this **[blog post describing an implementation of De Casteljau's algorithm](http://seant23.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/offset-bezier-curves/)**. *EDIT: I have to admit that I'm not sure how this implementation behaves with sharp turns.*

Comment: I only briefly scanned the PDF paper, but it does not appear to address the issue I illustrated.  Am I incorrect?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: After reading this question and the one on mathoverflow, I misunderstood the problem. I thought OP was trying to get exactly the curve that he describes, producing exactly the effect ("problem") that you describe, but that his algorithm was somehow failing. **@Iulian: Your definition of the offset curve in itself causes the folding (as Mr. Wizard points out)**

Answer (score 6):

I think you will run into trouble with your definition: "... draw a curve that is always at a certain distance from the normal to the surface of a given curve."

If you draw a series of lines inside a concave curve, at some point the line will fold back on itself, ultimately creating a geometric inversion.

Applied to an ellipse, for example:

[image]

Comment: Exactly this is the problem! Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: @Iulian well, for one thing, you will have to use a different definition.  Contemplate the problem illustrated above, and then decide how you would like to handle the situation.  Only then can it be implemented.  For example, consider the third object from the top in my illustration; would you accept the border of the inner white area as your new curve, even though at the ends it is farther from the ellipse than specified?

Comment: @Mr. I was going to post the same thing with bezier curves. You beat me this time :)

Comment: @Mr. I tried **Erosion[Rasterize[ParametricPlot[...]],DiskMatrix[5]]** and the results could be used with care

Comment: @belisarius I would need to see more to understand where you're going with that, but I don't expect that it would help Iulian.

Comment: @Mr. Probably not. That's the reason to post just a comment to you. See This http://ideone.com/NXPZA. Just a sketch.